# How to adjust the direction of movement of bullet sprites?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

In my program, when the keys are pressed, the image of the ship is flipped. I decided to bind the direction of the bullets to the flags of the ship's position. But I ran into the problem that all bullets take the direction of the ship when they are already fired. I need to keep the coordinate of the sprite when it is drawn.

```py
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from rocket import Rocket
from bullet import Bullet


class Cosmos:
    """Главный класс игры Cosmos"""

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Cosmos')
        self.fon_image = pygame.image.load('image/Fon.png')
        self.fon = self.fon_image.get_rect()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.rocket = Rocket(self.screen, self.settings)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()


    def key_event(self):
        """Обрабатывает нажатие клавиш"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.rocket.move_RIGHT = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.rocket.move_LEFT = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    self.rocket.move_UP = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    self.rocket.move_DOWN = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    self.fire_bullet()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.rocket.move_RIGHT = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.rocket.move_LEFT = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    self.rocket.move_UP = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    self.rocket.move_DOWN = False

    def fire_bullet(self):
        """Создание нового снаряда и включение его в группу"""
        new_bullet = Bullet(self.screen, self.settings, self.rocket)
        self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def run_game(self):
        """Обновляет события игры"""
        while True:
            self.screen.blit(self.fon_image, self.fon)
            self.key_event()
            self.rocket.update_rocket()
            for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
                bullet.draw_bullet()
                self.bullets.update(bullet)
            self.rocket.draw_rocket()
            pygame.display.flip()


game = Cosmos()
game.run_game()
```

```py
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Bullet(Sprite):
    """Класс для управления снарядами, выпущенными кораблем"""

    def __init__(self, screen, settings, rocket):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.settings = settings
        self.rocket = rocket
        self.color = self.settings.bullets_color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullets_width, self.settings.bullets_height)
        self.rect.midtop = rocket.rect.midtop
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def update(self, bullet):
        """Перемещение снаряда"""
        if self.rocket.image == self.rocket.image_right:
            bullet.x += 2
        if self.rocket.image == self.rocket.image_left:
            bullet.x -= 2
        if self.rocket.image == self.rocket.image_up:
            bullet.y -= 2
        if self.rocket.image == self.rocket.image_down:
            bullet.y += 2
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Рисует снаряд"""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

```py
import pygame


class Rocket:
    """Класс для управления кораблём"""

    def __init__(self, screen, settings):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load('image/pixil-frame-0.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.move_RIGHT = False
        self.move_LEFT = False
        self.move_UP = False
        self.move_DOWN = False
        self.image_right = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, -90)
        self.image_left = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 90)
        self.image_up = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 0)
        self.image_down = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 180)


    def update_rocket(self):
        """Флаги управления кораблём"""
        if self.move_RIGHT and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.image = self.image_right
            self.x += self.settings.rocket_speed
        if self.move_LEFT and self.rect.left > self.screen_rect.left:
            self.image = self.image_left
            self.x -= self.settings.rocket_speed
        if self.move_UP and self.rect.top > self.screen_rect.top:
            self.image = self.image_up
            self.y -= self.settings.rocket_speed
        if self.move_DOWN and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.image = self.image_down
            self.y += self.settings.rocket_speed
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_rocket(self):
        """Обновляет позицию корабля"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: the edit que is full, so i hope that whoever is editing adds which files are which.  `bullet.py` with the bullet class and `rocket.py` with the rocket class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that in `Bullet.update`, you use the current image of the rocket to determine in which direction the bullet is going. This means that any change of this image results in a change of direction. Instead of doing this, you should save the current direction upon creating a new `Bullet` instance and then use this saved direction to determine the direction of the rocket.

A possible implementation:

```py
class Bullet(Sprite):
    """Класс для управления снарядами, выпущенными кораблем"""

    def __init__(self, screen, settings, rocket):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.settings = settings
        self.rocket = rocket
        self.color = self.settings.bullets_color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullets_width, self.settings.bullets_height)
        self.rect.midtop = rocket.rect.midtop
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        if self.rocket.image == self.rocket.image_right:
            self.direction = "right"
        elif self.rocket.image == self.rocket.image_left:
            self.direction = "left"
        elif self.rocket.image == self.rocket.image_up:
            self.direction = "up"
        elif self.rocket.image == self.rocket.image_down:
            self.direction = "down"

    def update(self, bullet):
        """Перемещение снаряда"""
        if self.direction == "right":
            bullet.x += 2
        if self.direction == "left":
            bullet.x -= 2
        if self.direction == "up":
            bullet.y -= 2
        if self.direction == "down":
            bullet.y += 2
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Рисует снаряд"""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```